# Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister error

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I am not a frequent user of hibernate. I am trying to create Many-to-one mapping, but I get error (subj). I was looking for a mistakes in class declarations, also getter (last error), but everything seems to be correct. Does anyone see any mistakes in my code? Because I am not able to figuew out.

> Adres.java

```
package beans;

public class Adres {

  int id;
  String adresas;
  String adname;

  public Adres() {
  }

  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getAdresas() {
      return adresas;
  }

  public void setAdresas(String adresas) {
      this.adresas = adresas;
  }

  public String getAdname() {
      return adname;
  }

  public void setAdname(String adname) {
      this.adname = adname;
  }
}
```

> Men.java

```
package beans;

public class Men {

  int id;
  String name;

  Adres adres;

  public Men() {
  }

  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public Adres getAdd() {
      return adres;
  }

  public void setAdd(Adres adres) {
      this.adres = adres;
  }
}
```

> hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="hbm/Men.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hbm/Adres.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

> Men.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="beans.Men" table="MEN">
     <id column="id" name="id" type="int">
       <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <property column="name" name="name" type="string"/>
     <many-to-one class="beans.Adres" column="adres" name="adres" not-null="true"/>
   </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

> Adres.bbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="beans.Adres" table="ADRES">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="adresas" column="adresas" type="string"/>
    <property name="adname" column="adname" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> Main.java

```
private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

> Error log

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at main.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at main.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate getter method for property [beans.Men#adres]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findGetterMethod(ReflectHelper.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessBasicImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessBasicImpl.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:63)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Your naming conventions are really poor. You should give proper names for the classes and also to the properties of those class.

Comment: Do you think it would solve my problem? I believe it would not.

Comment: Its not about the solution to your problem.. Its about you writing sensible code which at least makes some sense to the person who is having a look at it..

Comment: @user2258338 After receiving an answer, you edited the question and fixed the code.  You're not supposed to do that, because the code in the question no longer reproduces the error in your question, and the answer doesn't match with the question anymore.  So I was looking for a `getAdd()` in the code in the question but couldn't find it until I looked at the revision history.  Perhaps you should roll the edit back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your getter and setter for `adres` property in `Men` class from

```
public Adres getAdd() {
    return adres;
}

public void setAdd(Adres adres) {
    this.adres = adres;
}
```

to

```
public Adres getAdres() {
    return adres;
}

public void setAdres(Adres adres) {
    this.adres = adres;
}
```

I suggest to give a **meaningful** variable names and related getters, setters!